# PHPMailer. How to add form data in the body of the message

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

The form submission is based on the PHPMailer library (ver. 6.0.7) I would like the form data, such as userName, userPhone and  userEmail, to be added to the header of the message. How to add form data in the message body. for example:

userName

userPhone

userEmail

Message content

How should it look like in my example?

**PHP**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 


if(!empty($_POST["send"])) {
    require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->Username = "**********";
    $mail->Password = "**********";

    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8"; 

    if (isset($_POST["userEmail"])) {
        $userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["userName"])) {
        $userName = $_POST["userName"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["userPhone"])) {
        $userPhone = $_POST["userPhone"];
    }   
    if (isset($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    }
    if (isset($_POST["userMessage"])) {
        $message = $_POST["userMessage"];
    }
    $mail->SetFrom("my email"); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($userEmail, $userName);
    $mail->AddAddress("my email");

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->WordWrap = 80;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = '**********';

    if (! empty($_FILES['attachment'])) {
        $count = count($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
        if ($count > 0) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
                if (! empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])) {

                    $tempFileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                    $fileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
                    $mail->AddAttachment($tempFileName, $fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (! $mail->Send()) {
        $message = "Ups :( Error";
        $type = "error";
    } else {

        $message = "Successfull";
        $type = "success";
    }
}

?>
```

**HTML and JavaScrip**t

```
<?php
require_once "mail-sending-script.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>PHP Contact Form with Add More File Attachment Option</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var valid = true;

            $(".info").html("");
            var userName = document.forms["mailForm"]["userName"].value;
            var userPhone = document.forms["mailForm"]["userPhone"].value;
            var userEmail = document.forms["mailForm"]["userEmail"].value;
            var subject = document.forms["mailForm"]["subject"].value;
            var userMessage = document.forms["mailForm"]["userMessage"].value;

            if (userName == "") {
                $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
                $("#userName").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }

            if (userPhone == "") {
                $("#userPhone-info").html("(required)");
                $("#userPhone").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (userEmail == "") {
                $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
                $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (!userEmail.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/))
            {
                $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
                $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }

            if (subject == "") {
                $("#subject-info").html("(required)");
                $("#subject").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (userMessage == "") {
                $("#userMessage-info").html("(required)");
                $("#userMessage").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
                valid = false;          
            }

            return valid;
        }

        function addMoreAttachment() {
            $(".attachment-row:last").clone().insertAfter(".attachment-row:last");
            $(".attachment-row:last").find("input").val("");
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>PHP Contact Form with Add More File Attachment Option</h1>

    <div class="attachment-form-container">
        <form name="mailForm" id="mailForm" method="post" action=""
            enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">

            <div class="input-row">
                <label style="padding-top: 20px;">Name</label> <span
                    id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br /> <input
                    type="text" class="input-field" name="userName"
                    id="userName" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Telefon</label> <span id="telefon-info"
                    class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                    class="input-field" name="telefon" id="telefon" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Email</label> <span id="userEmail-info"
                    class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                    class="input-field" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" />
            </div>

            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Subject</label> <span id="subject-info"
                    class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                    class="input-field" name="subject" id="subject" />
            </div>              

            <div class="input-row">
                <label>Message</label> <span id="userMessage-info"
                    class="info"></span><br />
                <textarea name="userMessage" id="userMessage"
                    class="input-field" id="userMessage" cols="60"
                    rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="attachment-row">
                <input type="file" class="input-field"
                    name="attachment[]">

            </div>

            <div onClick="addMoreAttachment();"
                class="icon-add-more-attachemnt"
                title="Add More Attachments">
                <img src="icon-add-more-attachment.png"
                    alt="Add More Attachments">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn-submit"
                    value="Wyślij" />

                <div id="statusMessage"> 
                        <?php
                        if (! empty($message)) {
                            ?>

                            <p class='<?php echo $type; ?>Message'><?php echo $message; ?></p>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've adapted this code from a very old example.

The easiest way to assemble your message body is with a [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (note comments in the docs on indenting):

```php
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Body = <<<EOT;
Name: $userName
Phone: $userPhone
Email: $userEmail
Message: $message
EOT;
```

Since your content is not HTML, there's no point in using `msgHTML()`; set `Body` directly, and disable HTML, as this example does.

A separate problem is that your file upload handling code is unsafe. Scrap it and start again using the code in [the multiple file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps).

Answer (score -1):

The following errors occur when submitting the form below:

> Syntax error, unexpected '<<'(T_SL)
>
> Syntax error, unexpected (T_STRING)**

My goal is to get the submit action to work. After getting the submit to work I want to  add a recaptcha to the form. I have tried the following:

```
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 
    
    
    if(!empty($_POST["send"])) {
        require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
        
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        
        $mail->Port = 465;
        
        $mail->Username = "********";
        $mail->Password = "*******";
        
        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8"; 
        
        if (isset($_POST["userEmail"])) {
            $userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
        }
        if (isset($_POST["userName"])) {
            $userName = $_POST["userName"];
        }
        if (isset($_POST["userPhone"])) {
            $userPhone = $_POST["userPhone"];
        }   
        if (isset($_POST["subject"])) {
            $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        }
        if (isset($_POST["userMessage"])) {
            $message = $_POST["userMessage"];
        }
        $mail->SetFrom("my email"); 
        $mail->AddReplyTo($userEmail, $userName);
        $mail->AddAddress("my emaill");
        
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->WordWrap = 80;
        
       $mail->isHTML(false);
       $mail->Body = <<<EOT;
       
        Name: $userName
        Phone: $userPhone
        Email: $userEmail
        Message: $message
        EOT;
        
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = '*********';
        
        for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $tempFileNamee = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $tempFileName)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($$tempFileName, $filename);
        } else {
            $$message .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $tempFileNamee;
        }
    }
        if (! $mail->Send()) {
            $message = "Ups :( Error";
            $type = "error";
        } else {
            
            $message = "Successfull";
            $type = "success";
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```